# Error : Result Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack when i am using tcl with c# dotnet

Tags: c#-4.0, tcl

I am Using the code

```
public int evalScript(string script) {
           return TclAPI.Tcl_Eval(interp,script);
       }
```

and i m getting error in 'return TclAPI.Tcl_Eval(interp,script);' line.

Comment: Ok, but what is the script?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Some details are missing: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)